# Find n:th word in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find nth word in a string. I am not allowed to use `StringToknizer` or `split` method from `String` class.

I now realize that I can use white space as a separator. The only problem is I don't know how to find the location of the first white space.

```
public static String pick(String message, int number){
  String lastWord;
  int word = 1;
  String result = "haha";

  for(int i=0; i<message.length();i++){
     if(message.charAt(i)==' '){enter code here
     word++;
     }
  }

  if(number<=word && number > 0 && number != 1){//Confused..
     int space = message.indexOf(" ");//improve
     int nextSpace = message.indexOf(" ", space + 1);//also check dat
     result = message.substring(space,message.indexOf(' ', space + 1));
  }

  if(number == 1){
     result =  message.substring(0,message.indexOf(" "));

  }
  if(number>word){
     lastWord = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
     return lastWord;
  }
  else return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to split at whitespaces or at spaces? The former is more than just the latter. If it's just the latter, `indexOf` is fine.

Comment: You're close.  Try a "while" loop that checks word count and a positive "indexOf" return value.  You can use substrings to keep your place in the input string.

Comment: @Lothar You may assume each space in the input is the transition between words.(Project)

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I'm not following you. :(

Comment: OK, then as @Mike said ;-) Otherwise you'd need regular expressions.

Comment: @Mike My friend told me to use for loop to check for white space. But I don't know how to connect for loop with nth number. :(

Comment: Below in answers is what I meant.

Comment: @MIke :) Burning my brain cells in order to understand

Comment: Sorry :P ... I posted an answer below. Did you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation is overcomplicated, hard to understand.

Consider this alternative algorithm:

- Initialize `index = 0`, to track your position in the input string
- Repeat n - 1 of times:

  - Skip over non-space characters
  - Skip over space characters
- At this point you are at the start of the n-th word, save this to `start`
- Skip over non-space characters
- At this point you are just after the end of the n-th word
- Return the substring between start and end

Like this:

```
public static String pick(String message, int n) {
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        while (index < message.length() && message.charAt(index) != ' ') index++;
        while (index < message.length() && message.charAt(index) == ' ') index++;
    }

    int start = index;
    while (index < message.length() && message.charAt(index) != ' ') index++;

    return message.substring(start, index);
}
```

Note that if `n` is higher than there are words in the input,
this will return empty string.
(If that's not what you want, it should be easy to tweak.)

Comment: @Andreas indeed I did :)

Comment: :)Sorry about this "late" comment. I was burning my brain cells to understand it. Thank You Sir!

Answer (score 0):

***CHEAT*** (using regex)<sup>1</sup>

```
public static String pick(String message, int number){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\W*" + (number > 1 ? "(?:\\w+\\W+){" + (number - 1) + "}" : "") + "(\\w+)").matcher(message);
    return (m.find() ? m.group(1) : null);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(pick("This is a test", 1));
System.out.println(pick("! This @ is # a $ test % ", 3));
System.out.println(pick("This is a test", 5));
```

*Output*

```
This
a
null
```

<sup>1) Only `StringTokenizer` and `split` are disallowed ;-)</sup>

Comment: It's kinda weird to disallow builtin classes and methods. Why don't they come up with a question that has the same problem space that won't benefit of builtins

Comment: My professor did not go that far. We are still doing array :( But I guess it's a good thing to know. Still, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This needs some edge case handling (e.g. there are fewer than n words), but here's the idea I was getting at.  This is similar to your solution, but IMO less elegant than janos'.

```
public static String pick(String message, int n) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    String word = "";
    int wordBegin = 0;
    int wordEnd = message.indexOf(' ');

    while (wordEnd >= 0 && wordCount < n) {
        word = message.substring(wordBegin, wordEnd).trim();
        message = message.substring(wordEnd).trim();
        wordEnd = message.indexOf(' ');
        wordCount++;
    }

    if (wordEnd == -1 && wordCount + 1 == n) {
            return message;
    }

    if (wordCount + 1 < n) {
            return "Not enough words to satisfy";
    }

    return word;
}
```

Comment: i thought trim has something to do with white space. Got that from my google experiences. :)

Comment: You're correct.  It's a little lazy, but because we're looking for a space to identify word beginnings/ends, it's easier to use trim() to remove the resultant spaces than it is to add/subtract 1 from the indexOf results when getting substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Most iteration in Java can now be replaced by streams. Whether this is an improvement is a matter of (strong) opinion.

```
int thirdWordIndex = IntStream.range(0, message.size() - 1)
    .filter(i -> Character.isWhiteSpace(message.charAt(i)))
    .filter(i -> Character.isLetter(message.charAt(i + 1)))
    .skip(2).findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new) + 1;
```